# PHP generate excel sheet from array and save in tmp folder

Tags: php, excel

i have written bellow code to generate and download excel sheet from array data

```
$data = array( 
array("NAME" => "John Doe", "EMAIL" => "john.doe@gmail.com", "GENDER" => "Male", "COUNTRY" => 
      "United States")
     );

$fileName = "codexworld_export_data-" . date('Ymd') . ".xls"; 

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\""); 
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 

$flag = false; 
foreach($data as $row) { 
if(!$flag) { 
    $tbody .= implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n"; 
    $flag = true; 
} 
$tbody .= implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n"; 
}
```

however i want this generated excel sheet to be downloaded in /tmp folder in the same project folder.

i added bellow code to put the excel sheet in /tmp but it is not working

```
file_put_contents('tmp/text.xls', $tbody);
```

Comment: In you're code you're not generating an Excel sheet anywhere. Maybe you're talking about generating a CSV file? Also: when sending a file to a client, it's not up to you, where the client stores that file - he picks the folder. Third: the way you're using `file_put_contents` you are writing the filename as text into `tmp/text.xls`, not the files contents. Please consider this input and clarify your question.

Comment: @FlorianMetzger-Noel code modified.

Comment: Please note, that XLS and CSV are completely different file formats. You are generating a CSV file in your script. Changing the suffix to ".xls" doesn't change anything about that fact. Please google "csv file format" and "xls file format" to understand the difference. If you want to generate XLS files, you need a php library like `phpspreadsheet`.

Comment: Also: From your scripting and explanations it seems that you got your concepts of client/server all mixed up. PHP typically runs on a server. Clients contact the server via browser. With `header(...)` you're preparing to send a file from server to client. With `file_put_contents` you are saving data into a file on the server. It all seems a bit confuse.